# Is sysdig agent able to monitor remote rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, sysdig

I've looked in the sysdig documentation but I wasn't able to find a clear answer.

I've configured a local container of a sysdig agent to try to connect to a remote rabbitmq but it seems to ignore it.

If I start a local instance of rabbitmq it's monitoring it. From the logs I see that for the local it detects it's PID, which makes me think that the agent needs to be on the same machine.

I've also started a ncat instance to forward the trafic from local to the remote sysdig and it made an attempt to monitor.

Does the sysdig agent need to be on the same host as the monitored application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is lurking in the [http](https://docs.sysdig.com/en/docs/sysdig-monitor/integrations-for-sysdig-monitor/integrate-applications-default-app-checks/http/#example-1) section of the documentation:

[If the URL is is remote from the agent, the user should use a process that is always running, such as “systemd”.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyYo0.png)

Using the same approach I was able to monitor 2 remote rabbit mq instances

Answer (score -1):

yes, This page describes the default configuration settings, how to edit the configuration to collect additional information, the metrics available for integration, and a sample result in the Sysdig Monitor UIsource https://docs.sysdig.com/en/docs/sysdig-monitor/integrations-for-sysdig-monitor/integrate-applications-default-app-checks/rabbitmq/

Comment: as noted in the question I have looked over the sysdig documentation, and the page you are pointing out.  And there is no definitive answer in that page that answers my questions, all the examples in the page are for local instances